# Celery task queuing in flask

Tags: python, celery

I have 3 celery tasks to be executed one by one. Because each tasks' output will be use as an input to the next task.

```
processSPP.apply_async((selevation,a,c,emailAdd), link=[emailfile.s(),deletefile.s()])
```

- 1st Task: processSPP (Generates a file)
- 2nd task: emailfile (Email the generated file to user)
- 3rd task: deletefile (Delete generated file from file system)

When I ran the flask app.

1st task executs first (Which is what I need)

The problem is 2nd and 3rd tasks start to execute at the same time as soon as 1st task finish. I want to start the 3rd task after finishing the 2nd task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want [celery.chain](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.chain):

```
chain(processSPP.s(selevation,a,c,emailAdd), emailfile.s(), deletefile.s()).apply_async()
```

The problem with your original code is that you are linking both `emailfile` and `deletefile` to `processSPP`, when what you actually want to do is link `emailfile` to `processSPP` and link `deletefile` to `emailfile`.

The equivalent using `link` as in your question would look kind of like:

```
processSPP.apply_async((selevation,a,c,emailAdd),
                       link=emailfile.s().set(link=deletefile.s()))
```